# iOS keychain: value not found

Tags: ios, sfhfkeychainutils

I write something into the keychain on a device with an older version of my project; then, I'd like to restore it with a new version - but I don't get any value back.

I'm doing the exact same thing, I use the same provisioning profile, bundle identifier... What could be the reason for not getting a value back with my newer project version? The query is the exact same one (using SFHFKeychainUtils):

```
(NSMutableDictionary *) $17 = 0x00982fd0 {
    acct = "com.abc.def.ghi.jkl.1";
    class = genp;
    svce = "SOME-THING";
}
```

Comment: Do you have the same app-id for the newer app version ? I mean exactly the same, matching the Seed-ID as well.

Comment: where can I check/change that?

Comment: the CFBundleIdentifier is the exact same one; but there's no seed id, just the com.company.whatever... stuff

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, seed-id is $AppIdentifierPrefix. On the other hand it might be the installation process that clears app-keychain, are you using ad-hoc installation or just running the newer app from Xcode ? The later would be not so good I think.

Comment: I have two Xcode windows open and install the app directly on the device; both on the exact same way. I try to get the AppIdentifierPrefix, but don't know how to get it...

Comment: As you know Xcode installation  process is not exactly the same as AdHoc, you might want to prepare two versions AdHoc distributions and install them with iTunes. The console log still might be accessed with Xcode Organizer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18635/discussion-between-swalkner-and-a-live)

Answer (score 0):

I think SFHFKeychainUtils is associative with codesign certificate, you should check your code signing identify and provisioning profile again.